# @Editable does not HtmlEncode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

We are using Sitecore 7 and MVC + Glass.mapper to build a new site.

Strange thing is that when we use `@Editable(x => x.SectionTitle)`, when in Edit mode the `SectionTitle` field's content gets `HtmlEncoded`, but not in preview or normal mode. (So if there is "" in the title field, it is output as `&lt;H1&gt;` in edit mode, but as `<H1>` in normal and preview)

If we use  `@HTML.Sitecore().Field("SectionTitle")` however, it always gets HtmlEncoded, and that is the behaviour we are looking for when using a single line text field...

Is this a Glitch in Glass?

---

Mike, this is the cshtml code:

```
<section>
    <H2> @Html.Sitecore().Field("SectieTitel")</H2>
    <h2>@Editable(x => x.SectieTitel)</h2>
    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("sectieInhoud")
</section>
```

We generate the models with T4 and TDS, this is the Sectie class generated:

```
namespace XXXXXXXXXXXXX
{

    public interface ISectie : IGlassItem // , ITagging
    {
            /// <summary>
        /// The SectieTitel field.
        /// <para></para>
        /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
        /// <para>Field ID: 2e364ec5-f0d4-4f16-baa3-fa9207f89cf6</para>
        /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
        /// </summary>
        string SectieTitel  {get; set;}

        }



    [SitecoreType(TemplateId="1760c3c6-a623-404a-98be-a0d4335a03cc")]
    public partial class Sectie  : GlassItem, ISectie 
    {
                private string _sectieTitel;

        /// <summary>
        /// The SectieTitel field.
        /// <para></para>
        /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
        /// <para>Field ID: 2e364ec5-f0d4-4f16-baa3-fa9207f89cf6</para>
        /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
        [SitecoreField("SectieTitel")]
        public virtual string SectieTitel  
        {
            get { return _sectieTitel; } 
            set { _sectieTitel = value; }
        }

            private object /* UNKNOWN */ _tags;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Tags field.
        /// <para></para>
        /// <para>Field Type: Multilist with Search</para>      
        /// <para>Field ID: 3a837ce8-7a1b-4cbf-8be9-9cebbdf1c48a</para>
        /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
        [SitecoreField("Tags")]
        public virtual object /* UNKNOWN */ Tags  
        {
            get { return _tags; } 
            set { _tags = value; }
        }


        public static string TemplateId { get { return "1760c3c6-a623-404a-98be-a0d4335a03cc"; } }
    }
```

}

In the cshtml you can see that I use the Sitecore MVC field and the glass way. Glass does not output htmlencoded strings while sitecore MVC does in preview and normal...

Erwin

Comment: Glass does not go through the RenderField pipeline unless you go through Editable. I would reckon that is why.

Comment: Hi Jens, if that is indeed the case then that would be a perfectly viable explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a blog post that details how you could solve this problem.

I will be adding the EncodedString type to the next Glass.Mapper.Sc release.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the model as well

Comment: Mike, tried your code, but same issue. We are running Glass 3.08. Could the comment of Jens be the answer?

Comment: Mike, in the GlassHTML.cs file, you check if we are in edit mode, and if not, the field gets rendered without HTML Encoding. Problem is that when I change that, Glass HTML Encodes all fields, so actually a field check should be done, to only HTMLencode the single and multiline text fields, but I have yet to figure out how to do that :-)

Comment: What is the field type you are trying to use?

Comment: Single line text is what I use, but should also be encoded for multi line text. This is what Sitecore also does default in the GetTextFieldValue Renderfield pipeline...

Comment: OK I think I understand now, you have a single line text field where users are entering html characters? For all fields but the Rich Text field Glass by passes the render field pipeline. I suppose what we need here is an intermediary type, something like EncodedString, this could be done with a datahandler

Comment: I tried to check for FieldType, but it has the value NotSet:

`
if (fieldConfig.FieldType == SitecoreFieldType.MultiLineText || fieldConfig.FieldType == SitecoreFieldType.SingleLineText)
                    {
                        firstPart = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(firstPart);
                    }
`
That would solve the problem...

Comment: The FieldType property is used by the code first aspects of Glass. Personally I tend not to put any HTML markup in Single Line Text or multiline text fields. I will do a quick blog post on encoded fields.

Comment: @MichaelEdwards The link above is broken. Did it get moved somewhere else?